# Creating a function inside another function to change the state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and wonder whether I have a simple syntax error or whether I'm going about this the wrong way (in a vanilla js way that it). I'm trying to just create a function (inside another function - inside the `next()` function, called `updateCurrentStatus`) that can update a simple array of objects (`Reviews`) so that the 'next' object's property 'current' changes to 'true' and the other objects' 'current' properties change to false.

It might make more sense seeing the reviews.json:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Peter Lahm",
      "comment": "Was ok. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 3.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Simon Arnold",
      "comment": "Nice - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": true,
      "current": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Claire Pullen",
      "comment": "Great - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": false
    }
]
```

The 'Simon Arnold' review is the 'current' review by default, so in order to display the next review I want the 'Claire Pullen' review to change the current property to true and the others false - so I wrote this function:

```
next() {
    console.log("next() execution start");

    for (let i = 0; i < Reviews.length; i++) { // 1. go through each review
      let review = Reviews[i];

      if (review["current"] && i < Reviews.length - 1) { // 2. if current one AND not last one
        updateCurrentStatus(Reviews[i + 1]); // 3. make the next review true & the rest false
      } else {
        updateCurrentStatus(Reviews[0]); // 4. else make the first review true & the rest false
      }

      function updateCurrentStatus(obj) {
        Reviews.forEach(function(rev) {
          if (obj == rev) {
            obj.current == true;
          } else {
            obj.current == false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("next() execution end");
  }
```

However, I'm getting this error and I don't know why, apparently in line `function updateCurrentStatus(obj) {`:

```
Error in index.js (54:7)
',' expected.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

For more visibility, here's the rest of the index code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";
import "./fontawesome.min.css";
import ReviewsLeftArea from "./ReviewsLeftArea";
import ReviewsRightArea from "./ReviewsRightArea";
import AllReviews from "./AllReviews";
import Reviews from "./reviews.json";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      reviews: Reviews,
      avgRating: (
        Reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating, 0) / Reviews.length
      ).toFixed(1),
      totalReviews: Reviews.length,
      initialReview: Reviews.find(({ init }) => init === true),
      currentReview: Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true)
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Reviews.forEach(function(review) {
      if (review.init) {
        review["current"] = true;
      } else {
        review["current"] = false;
      }
    });
  }

  next() {
    console.log("next() execution start");

    for (let i = 0; i < Reviews.length; i++) { // 1. go through each review
      let review = Reviews[i];

      if (review["current"] && i < Reviews.length - 1) { // 2. if current one AND not last one
        updateCurrentStatus(Reviews[i + 1]); // 3. make the next review true & the rest false
      } else {
        updateCurrentStatus(Reviews[0]); // 4. else make the first review true & the rest false
      }

      function updateCurrentStatus(obj) {
        Reviews.forEach(function(rev) {
          if (obj == rev) {
            obj.current == true;
          } else {
            obj.current == false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("next() execution end");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="reviews-area-wrap">
        <div id="reviews-area-inner">
          <ReviewsLeftArea
            totalReviews={this.state.totalReviews}
            avgRating={this.state.avgRating}
          />
          <ReviewsRightArea currentReview={this.state.currentReview} />
        </div>
        <AllReviews
          currentReview={this.state.currentReview}
          reviews={this.state.reviews}
        />
        {setTimeout(this.next, 3000)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root-cont"));
```

And FYI, the 'current' properties are actually all null by default and changed by `componentWillMount`. I hope I've explained this clearly. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing parenthesis is missing in forEach method.

```
Reviews.forEach(function(rev) {
      if (obj == rev) {
        obj.current = true;
      } else {
        obj.current = false;
      }
})
```

And just for starters, this function declaration can be moved out of for loop as a function expression. Like so

```
const updateCurrentStatus = (obj) => {
        Reviews.forEach(function(rev) {
          if (obj == rev) {
            obj.current = true;
          } else {
            obj.current = false;
          }
        })
}
for (let i = 0; i < Reviews.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, although the function doesn't seem to be updating the Reviews for some reason. Do you know why it wouldn't do this?

Comment: I have corrected the if-else blocks to assign the value now. That could have been a cause.